# AngularJS - parent scope is not updating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'll try to explain the problem with the example. Example is simplified, so it's not very logical, but anyway..

Let's say I have such view

```
<div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <button ng-add-item="items">Add Item</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}} <button ng-change-item="item">Change item</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I have two directives:

1) ngAddItem - which adds dummy item (after click)

2) ngUpdateItem - which changes item (after click)

The problem is that 1) works great, but second - not..

http://jsfiddle.net/pbmnL/2/

P.S. I know I can use ng-click and many other things in this example. This is just simplified example.

Thanks for a help!..

UPDATE: If I change just a name property everything works fine!
http://jsfiddle.net/pbmnL/4/

But in real example I still need to change entire object..

Comment: The `items` list does not changed. So, as it has a different scope, you have to update the list itself to change in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work because with this line:

```
_item = _changed_item;
```

you just point local variable _item to another object but do not update the item in the list.

As a solution you may use angular.copy - it replaces all properties of one object with properties from another one.

```
angular.copy(_changed_item, _item);
```

Here is [jsfiddle that works](http://jsfiddle.net/GRaAL/Mu3aT/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$element.bind('click', function () {
    $scope.$parent.item.name = 'changed name';
    $scope.$apply();
});
```